# When to use conjunctive adverb: "otherwise"?

Tags: adverbs, conjunctions

The correct answer to the #50 is J. I was to ask what does the phrase "far from heavenly" mean? To me, it seems that the narrator disagrees with Frank Sinatra; therefore, I consider that H could also be a possible answer.

How can this issue be solved?

Note that the answer to #49 is D

[image: ACT 72G]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that the narrator is disagreeing with Sinatra.  "Far from heavenly" is a strong way to say "not heavenly."

An important word in the sentence is the first word, *though*.  *Though* is used to introduce contrast between two phrases; its meaning is like if *but* or *however* were used between the phrases.

The original text uses *consequently*, but this doesn't make much sense; that adverb should only be used when you're describing a *consequence* of something.  [For example](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/consequently), "All the shops were closed, and consequently we couldn't buy any food."

*Otherwise* doesn't need to be used here to suggest contrast, because *though* already does that.  Furthermore, it doesn't make grammatical sense to use it here.  [*Otherwise*, as a conjunction](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/otherwise), is used after a hypothetical scenario, such as an order or suggestion, to discuss the result if that scenario does not happen.  But in this case, the first phrase is not hypothetical; it's not an order or a suggestion.  It's a fact: Frank Sinatra did sing about the bridge's "lovely views from Heaven."

Answer (score 1):

You are right that [otherwise](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/otherwise) can suggests that something is different. Adverb positioning is somewhat flexible, but the positioning of 50H would not be right. Here is an example of a correct usage:

> The police believe he is the thief, but all the evidence suggests otherwise

To fit the pattern of the question in the test, the sentence would have to be:

> Though frank Sinatra sang about the bridge's "lovely views from heaven", my first view was otherwise.

When used between commas, **otherwise** has the meaning **except for what has just been referred to**.

> The buffet meal was disappointing but the evening was, **otherwise**, a complete success.

Comment: Can you list some words that behave like **otherwise**?

Comment: @ParthMaske: Words that have different meanings depending on where you put them in the sentence? There are lots. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/so